# React how to re-render component only when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I tried my best to search for a similar question before posting. I've got a Summary component in my project that accepts three user selected props (part #, start date, and end date), calls an API, then displays the fetched data. My problem is that the component re-renders every time the user changes one of the parameters (e.g. picks a new start date).

Ideally, the user would instead click an "Apply" button that would re-render the component using the set of three props. I tried using React.useRef() to create a reference to the component that I would use to update the Summary's state in a button's onClick event but no luck. I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to structure this situation. I'm editing the question to provide an extremely simple example below.

This is a sample application with an App.js and a Summary.jsx component. The code for App.js is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import Summary from "./Components/Summary";

function App() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = React.useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = React.useState("");
  const [input3, setInput3] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input1"
        onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
       />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input2"
        onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input3"
        onChange={(e) => setInput3(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          alert("button has been clicked.");
        }}
      >
        Apply
      </button>
      <Summary i1={input1} i2={input2} i3={input3} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code for Summary.jsx (contained in a Components folder) is as follows:

```
import React from "react";

const Summary = (props) => {
  return (
    <h1>{`Input 1: ${props.i1} Input 2: ${props.i2} Input 3: 
${props.i3}`}</h1>
  );
};

export default Summary;
```

You can see that as the user types into any of the inputs, it automatically re-renders the components as the state changes and thus the props that are supplied to the Summary component. Ideally, I would like no change to occur until the user hits the Apply button (I just supplied a bogus alert message as the onClick functionality for now).

Comment: Yeah I'd say it will be hard to figure out without code and reproduction steps. Refer to link below in case you need guidelines what is important to include when asking question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok I will include some sample code. I should just edit my original question correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the `Summary` component to be re-rendered every time the parent component changes, I suggest using conditional rendering

- Have a state `isSubmited` that defaults False, and set to True when user clicks Apply
- Only render `Summary` when `isSubmmited` is True. If false, renders nothing (null)

If you want to switch `isSummited` back, pass a handler function `setBack = () => setSubmited(false)` as a props to the appropriate component

Something like this:

```js
// App.js
function App() {
  const [input1, setInput1] = React.useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = React.useState("");
  const [isSubmitted, setSubmitted] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input1"
        value={input1}
        onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input2"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          alert("button has been clicked.");
          setSubmitted(true);
        }}
      >
        Apply
      </button>
      {/* Ternary operator */}
      {isSumitted ? (
        <Summary
          i1={input1}
          i2={input2}
          afterDataFetch={() => setSubmitted(false)}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}

// Summary.js
function Summary(props) {
  const { i1, i2, i3, afterDataFetch } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    // This will trigger 'setSubmitted(false)'
    afterDataFetch();
  });
}
```

Edit: As per request, to implement "keeping the old state and only send new state to Summary when click Submit", I have come up with a solution:

- Besides the 3 input states, I also have a `data` state that is responsible for keeping the old states of the individual input fields (states from the previous Submit)
- Therefore, the `data` state will only get updated when user clicks Submit

```js
// App.js
function App() {
  const initial = {
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
  };
  const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState(initial);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input1"
        value={input1}
        onChange={(e) => setInput1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="input2"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => setInput2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          setData({
            input1: input1,
            input2: input2,
          });
        }}
      >
        Apply
      </button>
      <Summary i1={data.input1} i2={data.input2} />
    </>
  );
}

// Summary.js
function Summary(props) {
  const { i1, i2 } = props;
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify({ i1, i2 })}</pre>;
}

export default React.memo(Summary);
```

Note the use of [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) in the Summary.js file. This is for some rendering optimization. As you can imagine, the Summary component may get re-rendered (through `setInput1` or `setInput2`), even though the `data` state has not changed. Therefore, using `React.memo`, per the docs:

> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to `React.memo` for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

If your Summary component fetches API every time it re-renders, that could be a pretty good optimization (prevent refetching when data has not changed - although you could use solution like "useSWR" to cache response anyway)

Comment: Thank you for your response Bao. I had considered using a method like this. My only problem with this is that the user should be able to hit apply multiple times with different input values. With the code provided, it seems that there is no way to switch isSubmitted back to false.

Comment: you could pass a handler function as a props to `Summary`. Check my edit

Comment: That's awesome thanks for your help Bao. I'm most interested in getting this functional, which you've helped me do. However, I am wondering if the way this is set up would be considered best practices? Or is there another way you would recommend I should have structured it?

Comment: I don't know much about best practices, but if maybe I would add another `useState` hook in App.js: `[data, setData] = useState(null)`, and fetched the data inside the App.js. That is, `<button id="apply" onClick={fetchDataAndSetData} />`. Then I would pass the data into the Summary component as a prop: `<Summary data={data} />`. The Summary component is purely for display/presentation purposes - the main logic is handled through App.js. But again, your situation may be different, and I don't know all the details. P/s: Please consider upvote and select my answer if it solves your issue

Comment: I really appreciate your patience with me Bao. I had to unselect the answer as solved because a small problem popped up. Just using the simple example (no API call) with your isSubmitted state, the Summary pops up for an instant then disappears. This is because the state changes once (isSubmitted becomes true) and the ternary operator allows App.js to render a Summary component. However, after rendering the useEffect fires which causes isSubmitted to become false. So App.js re-renders and the ternary operator returns false. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It seems like what you need is another state, to store the "old" states of the input fields (state from the previous Submit - and only get updated when you click Submit).  Check out my edit